# R shiny App Deploy error on windows

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to deploy my app on shinyapps.io. But I am getting the following error. I am using windows machine and R 1.1.3.

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages(new.packages) :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : unable to install packages
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Can anybody help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you post a minimal example of the app code?

Answer (score 1):

I was installing and loading the packages in R code of global.R. I came to know that, rsconnect and shiny detects packages themselves and as they not allow to install any package by install.packages() command.

So, I removed all installing packages from the code and just loaded it.

It worked fine.

Thanks